# Mac unable to resolve dependencies with gradle

Tags: java, macos, scala, gradle

I have a simple build.gradle that pulls in a few java dependencies.  On my mac, gradle keeps saying that its unable to resolve dependencies for any jar.  This only started happening yesterday, rebooting doesn't solve this.  I have tried running the project on linux and things work just as expected.  Any idea whats up with my mac thats causing this?

```
Cause 2: java.lang.InternalError
    [...]
    at javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport$4.run(SecuritySupport.java:92)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport.getResourceAsStream(SecuritySupport.java:87)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findJarServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:288)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:255)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:121)
    at org.apache.ivy.util.XMLHelper.getDocBuilder(XMLHelper.java:208)
    at org.apache.ivy.util.XMLHelper.parseToDom(XMLHelper.java:193)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.m2.PomReader.<init>(PomReader.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.GradlePomModuleDescriptorParser.parseDescriptor(GradlePomModuleDescriptorParser.java:91)
    [...]
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
```

When I run on linux, things are working fine.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = '1.7'
}

apply plugin: 'scala'

repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3'
  compile('com.twitter:finagle-core_2.10:6.9.0') {
    exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
    exclude group: 'org.mockito', module: 'mockito-all'
    exclude group: 'org.scala-tools.testing', module: 'specs_2.10'
    exclude group: 'org.scalatest', module: 'scalatest_2.10'
  }
  compile('com.twitter:finagle-http_2.10:6.9.0') {
    exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
    exclude group: 'org.mockito', module: 'mockito-all'
    exclude group: 'org.scala-tools.testing', module: 'specs_2.10'
    exclude group: 'org.scalatest', module: 'scalatest_2.10'
  }
  compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.10:2.3.0'
}
```

Using Java 7 and Gradle 1.7

Answer (score 2):

Try dropping maven and/or gradle cache for the dependencies that make problems or just altogether:

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle/
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/
```

Please note that the later may lead to significant network traffic and build times next time the build is run!

Comment: Doesn't work. It will redownload everything, but still produces the error.  I also tried running the scala command to launch a REPL and got the same message:

    scala> [init] error: error while loading <root>, error in opening zip file

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my java got corrupted; reinstalling java fixed the issue